# chart js label not showing

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I've embedded a pie chart from chart.js and referenced an old question on StackOverflow to show the labels. However, the labels only show when you hover over the chart. The code I've used is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       var pieData = [{
                value : 30,
                color : "#F38630",
                label : 'Sleep',
                labelColor : 'white',
                labelFontSize : '16'
            },
                  {
                value : 30,
                color : "#F34353",
                label : 'Sleep',
                labelColor : 'white',
                labelFontSize : '16'
            }];

        var myPie = new Chart(document.getElementById("piechart").getContext("2d")).Pie(pieData, {                     
            animationSteps: 100,
            animationEasing: 'easeInOutQuart'   });
    });
```

Any ideas on how I can show the labels?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I copied the JS from: 
http://jsfiddle.net/nCFGL/223/

```
//Chart.js
```

//Define the global Chart Variable as a class.
var Chart = function(context){

```
var chart = this;
```

to make the chart.js file. Something is missing in the chart.js file I downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        stacked: false,
        beginAtZero: true,
        scaleLabel: {
            labelString: 'Month'
        },
        ticks: {
            stepSize: 1,
            min: 0,
            autoSkip: false
        }
    }]
}
```